# GoBack performance

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm wondering how to improve GoBack performance for metro app.

If I have 2 pages (let say homepage and secondpage) and if I navigate to my secondepage then pressing back button it seems that my application is freezing during 1sec. It is not a real issue but it is not good for user experience !.

- I tried to change the navigation cache mode and it does not fix the
  issue.
- I tried to deal with the navigation mode and only refresh the
  previous page (in my case: homepage) if the navigation mode is not
  new (again no change).

Is there any other solution?

PS: you can use the default grid template to see this issue.

Comment: It looks like you have, but check out [this](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-navigation-cache-or-why-going-back-to-previous-page-creates-a-new-instance-of-the-page/) article. If that doesn't help, you may want to check out the [WinRT Xaml Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/), which has the ability to asyncrhonously load (and pre-load) the pages.